# What's the best way to solve $1 = A(x^2+1) + (Bx+C)(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, partial-fractions

What's the best way to solve $$1 = A(x^2+1) + (Bx+C)(x+1)$$

I let $x=-1$ and got $A=\frac{1}{2}$
But what sub is ideal to find B&C

This gets messy quick, I think.

Instead, I started over, and I grouped like terms

$$1 = Ax^2+A+Bx^2+Bx+Cx+C$$
This led to $$A+B=0$$ $$B+C=0$$ $$A+C=1$$
This led to $B=-\frac{1}{2}$

$C=\frac{1}{2}$

and solved using my A=1/2
But, I did not like that I had to mix techniques.

Comment: You did it exactly right.

Comment: I think the way that you used to find $A$ can not be used to find $B,C$ and we have to find them by the way that you wrote .

Comment: You could use $x=i=\sqrt {-1}$ to eliminate the term in $A$, but that is no easier than what you have done. In this kind of question mixing techniques is often the most efficient way. On the other hand if you are looking to generalise a procedure to show that it can always be done, it can be quite useful to generalise a simple procedure - which may be inefficient in practice.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the verification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each step take advantage of your previous findings.$$1 = A(x^2+1) + (Bx+C)(x+1)$$

$$x=-1 \implies A=\frac {1}{2}$$
$$ x=0 \implies A+C=1 $$

Thus $$C =1/2$$
 $$x=1 \implies 2A+2(B+C)=1$$ 
Thus $$B+C=0 \implies B=-\frac {1}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Grouping like terms is the best way to solve for the *coefficients* of any polynomial. Like @Paul said, you did it exactly right.

First, we group like terms together:
$$A(x^2 + 1) + (Bx + C)(x+1) = 1$$
$$(A+B)x^2 + (B+C)x + A+C=1 + 0x + 0x^2$$
Second, we solve for the coefficients:
$$A+B=0\implies A=-B$$
$$B+C=0 \implies C = -B = A$$
$$A + C = 1 \implies A+A = 2A=1 \implies A = \frac{1}{2}.$$
$$B=-A=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$C = A = \frac{1}{2}.$$
You used mixed techniques, which is fine and mathematically valid; however, it was unnecessary here.